# Swift Sorting Out Data From Firebase via Timestamp

Tags: swift, sorting, tableview

**Edit:** Added screenshot of my example.

I have a firebase database where users upload information, as well as a date and time. I have successfully retrieved all this data, however I did want to ask a question regards to sorting information. Currently, my tableview which shows this data just shows the order in which users uploaded this information. I have played around with 'sort' command which successfully sorts out ascending or descending data by users.

However, I would like to sort out data based on the time users have chosen not based on who posted it first. Below is an example as well as my code. If someone can point out any improvements, that would be great!

**Input for example:**
User A posts first at a time of 9 AM.
User B posts second at a time of 10 AM.
User C posts third at a time of 6 AM.

**Sort by code:**
User A (9AM), User B (10AM), User C (6AM)
**OR**
User C (6AM), User B (10AM), User A (9AM)

**What I Would Like:**
User C (6AM), User A (9AM), User B (10AM)

**Code**

```
func fetchData(for date: String) {
    
    guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let journalRef = Database.database().reference().child("\(userId)/Events")

    journalRef.removeAllObservers()
        self.databaseRef = journalRef.child(date)
        self.databaseRef.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        self.events.removeAll()
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0 {
            for eventsFirebase in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                if let eventsObject = eventsFirebase.value as? [String: AnyObject],
                   let eventTitle = eventsObject["eventTitle"] as? String,
                   let eventDay = workoutsObject["eventDay"] as? String,
                   let eventTiming = workoutsObject["eventTiming"] as? String {
                   let eventInDepth = EventInformation(id: eventInDepth.key, eventDay: eventDay, eventTiming: eventTiming, eventTitle: eventTitle)
                   self.events.append(eventInDepth)
 


                   self.events.sort(by: {$0.eventTiming > $1.eventTiming}) // this is it
                }
            }
        }
        self.eventsList.reloadData()
    })
}
```

I have tried the sort by code which sorts the time in which users have actually uploaded their data however i want to sort by the time they have chosen - 'eventTiming'.

Below is a screenshot to visualise what I mean. I would like it to be in a chronological time order, not in a chronological order from when it was uploaded. So in the below example, the order should be 6:00 AM, 6:30 AM and 7:00 AM.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feHv0.jpg)

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the first post of every user? What does the `eventTiming` `String` look like?

Comment: What happens if you move the sorting to after the _for_ loop, wouldn't that solve the issue or is there more to the problem?

Comment: @burnsi Thank you for your comment, I have uploaded an image to visualise my issue. It is not the first post of every user, rather want to sort out the 'eventTiming' in chronological order. An example could be a doctors appointment, when people make appointments if the first one made an appointment for 3 pm and the second made an appointment for 9 am. The list would adapt to show 9 am first for a chronological flow! The eventTiming string is the time so for example "6:00 am" or "7:00 pm".

Comment: Although, now that I write about this, I think the problem may lie in sorting out this string as it has a suffix of AM or PM. Rather, I think i may need to save it as a timestamp 1970 way?

Comment: Or in a 24h format or in minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your “eventTiming” is a date/time **string**, not a numeric date or time. That is going to mess you up, since those will be sorted by string sorting rules, not date/time sorting rules.

You’d be better off saving dates/times as numeric offsets from the UNIX epoch date. (Number of seconds/milliseconds since Midnight GMT on January 1, 1970.) Sort them by comparing numbers.

There are also date string formats that work for string date sorting (4 digit year, followed by 2 digit month with leading zeros, followed by 2 digit day with leading zeros, followed by 24 hour time with leading zeros for the hours, minutes, and seconds.)

Failing that, add a lazy property `eventTimingDate` to each struct that uses a static DateFormatter to convert your date string to a `Date` object. (By making it a lazy property you’ll only do the date string to date conversion once per object.)